# How to use groupBy in bean class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, playframework, javabeans

> I have this code but while running i m getting error like...

**cannot find symbol
symbol:   method groupBy(java.lang.String)
location: interface com.avaje.ebean.ExpressionList<models.ClusterResources>**

```
    public static List<ClusterResources> getClusterLeaderByEmpId(int cluster_id) {
        List<ClusterResources> clusterLeaders = Ebean.find(ClusterResources.class)
                .where()
                .eq("cluster_id", cluster_id)
                .groupBy("cluster_leader")
                .findList();
            if (clusterLeaders == null)
                clusterLeaders = new ArrayList<>();
        return clusterLeaders;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your model ClusterResources it's a bit hard to know what you want to achieve, but Ebean will generally add "group by" automatically when needed, e.g. if you select something that needs grouping:

```
.select("cluster_leader, MAX(cluster_value)")
```

Check out these links:
[Ebean aggregation](https://ebean.io/docs/query/aggregation) and [Ebean select](https://ebean.io/docs/query/select)